# How to enable all Tag Descriptions in loop?

Tags: tags

As the title states all I'm trying to do is get the descriptions for all tags inside the loop on my INDEX.php page to show up.

I know you can use code to call specific tag descriptions but I want to avoid that if possible since I'll have hundreds of tags all of which I want to show descriptions for.

Is there a way to modify the `get_tags` tag in the loop to display descriptions following each tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Modified from the `get_tags()` Codex Example*

```
$tags = get_the_tags(); // for the specific post
// $tags = get_tags(); // all tags
$html = '<div class="post_tags">';
foreach ( $tags as $tag )
{
    $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );

    $html .= "Describtion for ".ucfirst( strtolower( $tag->name ) ).": $tag->description";
    $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>{$tag->name}</a>";
    }

$html .= '</div>';
echo $html;
```

Comment: This is great man. I appreciate that you took the time to write this, thank you.

I should of been a bit more specific and will be in the future. 

Is there a way to limit the tags to only the ones associated with each post? (Rather than displaying all of them in the database.)

Comment: See updated A and save the [link to the Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference).